# Below Code displays differently in Chrome and IE

Tags: html

```
    <div class="wholediv">
       <div class="rightdiv">
         <strong>Your Company Name</strong><br />
         Evergreen Terrace 742<br />
         Kansas Missouri<br />
         Phone: 432-653-3121<br />
         sales@thetiecompany.com   </div>
       <div class="sitemap">
       <a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Sitemap</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
       </div>
</div>

    div div.wholediv
{
height:97px;
width:500px;
float:left;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
div div.sitemap
{ 
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  width:200px;
  height:87px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
   font: 0.7em Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;  
}
div div.rightdiv
{
float:left;
position:static;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
width:200px;
height:87px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:10px;
font: 0.7em Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

IE displays like this.
[image]
Chrome displays like this.
[image]

Comment: this is better than your previous question, but still not very useful. Please either post a live link (to a JSFiddle or similar), and / or describe the problem *in detail*. Otherwise, people have to painstakingly copy+paste your code - something most won't be going to do.

Comment: A description of the problem would be helpful. It would also be good if you could show a sample page, as the issue may not be entirely dependant on this small snippet (e.g. surrounding elements or cascading styles could add to it).

Answer (score 0):

You have a block-level element that has both a width and padding. That's at least one thing that's going to cause trouble in IE because of the different box-model.

More info about box models: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

edit after you added the images: 
atleast position: static & position:relative shouldn't be needed here the way you're using them. You could start debugging by removing padding from the elements. Padding is probably the thing in IE that breaks the "sitemap"-row.

You're not including in the code the part that has the logo-image etc so can't comment on that part. I think you should read about the box-models and apply that. Also it the way position is used looks quite random, so you could study that a little bit. More info in about positioning in http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

Comment: Will DreamWeaver CS8 solve my problem? Does it have browser compatibility checks?

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani get rid of Dreamweaver, learn how to write HTML yourself.

Comment: Even if I avoid Dreamweaver, I will still face the problem of browser compatibility.

Comment: What if I maintain 2 stylesheets for IE and chrome respectively and change the css stylesheet at runtime. Will this solve my problem?

Comment: @chandan it will solve your issue yes. But its not a good way to approach it. It can be fixed, just look at the links provided.

Comment: You could add classes declaring the browser to the DOM body-element. For example .ie6, .ie7, .chrome etc. Then you could write your CSS like .box {width: 200; padding: 10px; } .ie6 .box {width: 180px;} which would make them the same width in different browsers.